# AWS S3 - How to get all files that are GLACIER storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

My goal is to convert all files that are currently GLACIER storage class to STANDARD using `aws cli s3api`. In order to do this, I need to first get a list of all these files, then fire a `restore` command, and eventually a `copy` command to change them all to STANDARD.

The problem is, the number of files are too large (~ 5 million), which eventually results in `core dump segmentation fault` error if the max item exceeds 600k to 700k. If I don't supply the `--max-item` parameter, I would get the same error. So I couldn't get anymore files below 700k threshold. Here's the command I used:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==`GLACIER`]' --max-item 700000 > glacier.txt
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: How about `--output text`?  Otherwise, I believe it's trying to build one giant JSON object.

Comment: The script only save the objects that are GLACIER storage class.

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand how that is related to changing the output format of aws-cli.  I'm suggesting that you *add* that option, retaining the others.  Does that not work?

Comment: Still got same error, anyway I already wrote a small script using `--starting-token`, it might be what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I discovered the option `--starting-token` from `list-objects` command. So I wrote a script to scan all items in batch of 100k objects. This script will output a file containing the S3 key of all GLACIER object.

```
#!/bin/bash
BUCKET="s3-bucket-name"
PREFIX="foldername"
PROFILE="awscliprofile"
MAX_ITEM=100000

var=0
NEXT_TOKEN=0
while true; do

    var=$((var+1))

    echo "Iteration #$var - Next token: $NEXT_TOKEN"

    aws s3api list-objects \
    --bucket $BUCKET \
    --prefix $PREFIX \
    --profile $PROFILE \
    --max-item $MAX_ITEM \
    --starting-token $NEXT_TOKEN > temp

    awk '/GLACIER/{getline; print}' temp >> glacier.txt

    NEXT_TOKEN=$(cat temp | grep NextToken | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\("\|",\)//g')
    if [ ${#NEXT_TOKEN} -le 5 ]; then
        echo "No more files..."
        echo "Next token: $NEXT_TOKEN"
        break
        rm temp
    fi
    rm temp
done
echo "Exiting."
```

After that I can use `restore-object` and finally `copy-object` to change the storage class of all these files to STANDARD. See more scripts [here](https://github.com/gl-lamhnguyen/s3-glacier-tools/blob/master/change-storage-class.sh). Hope this helps anyone who needs to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

here is one liner solution

```
 aws s3api list-objects --bucket *bucket-name*| grep "StorageClass" > nonglacier.txt
```

then you can grep storage class using

```
cat nonglacier.txt | grep GLACIER | wc -l
```

can also be summarized as

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket-name>| grep "StorageClass" |  grep GLACIER | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better

`` aws s3api list-objects --bucket "foobar" --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==`GLACIER`].Key' --output text  >> allGlacier.txt ``